# Embedded Development Support plugin does not generate CMake files in CLion on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: stm32, linux, stm32cubemx

I can build, run and debug my old projects. 
But when I try to import new STM32CubeMX project, nothing happens. No `CMakeLists.txt` file created. Pressing '`update CMake project with STM32CubeMX`' from menu Tools -> CMake has no effect.
My system is Ubuntu 19.10, CLion 2019.3.3, openjdk version "14-ea".

Comment: I think it is more like a question to ST support.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Even more to Jet Brains support, but just in case somebody has same issue

Answer (score 1):

In short, the problem is that STM32CubeMX does not generate `.ld` file for SW4STM32 project. The issue is described [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-17776) for MacOS and also applies to Ubuntu 19. The solution for me was to completely remove Java, then install OpenJDK 11.